# django: How to create table consist of parent and child table, but with only latest child?

Tags: templates, django-models, django-views, parent-child

I have one-to-many relationship between model Post and Update.  What I need is list (table) of combine Post entry with the latest Update entry. Something like this:

```
 Title                        Status            % Progress         Date
 Zulu great one            zulu two status          20        Nov. 19, 2019, 10 a.m.
 Create tables         status create table dua      40        Nov. 19, 2019, 9:45 a.m.
 Remember my first post    status tiga              40        Nov. 19, 2019, 9:43 a.m.
```

What I want is only latest Update (Status, Progree, Date) per Post (Title), but not list all Update.(see below code)

I have models.py as follows:

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
#....


class Update(models.Model):
posting = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="opdates")
status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
progress = models.IntegerField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
#...
```

And views.py as follows:

```
def post_list(request, template_name="post_list.html"):
posts = Post.objects.all()
updates = Update.objects.order_by('-created_date')

ctx = {}
ctx['posts'] = posts
ctx['updates'] = updates
return render(request, template_name, ctx)
```

And my template as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>% Progress</th>
    <th>Date</th>
 </tr>
  <tbody>
      {% for up in updates %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ up.posting.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ up.status }}</td>
    <td>{{ up.progress }}</td>
    <td>{{ up.created_date }}</td>
    </tr>
      {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

NOTE:
I can do run python manage.py shell as follows:

```
  >>> from blog.models import Post, Update
  >>> p = Post.objects.get(title='Create tables')
  >>> p
  <Post: Create tables>
  >>> p.opdates.order_by('-created_date')
  <QuerySet [<Update: status create table dua>, <Update: status create satu>]>
  >>> p.opdates.order_by('-created_date').first()
  <Update: status create table dua>
  >>> p.opdates.order_by('-created_date').first().progress
  40
```

how can I translate that to views.py (or models.py or template)?  Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Okey,,, I got this figured out,,, I turns out I could write in template as follows:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>% Progress</th>
    <th>Date</th>
 </tr>
<tbody>
{% for p in posts %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ p.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.opdates.last.status }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.opdates.last.progress }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.opdates.last.created_date }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I used related name "opdates" who hold ForeignKey in Update model.